# How to change the color of this loading bar for my Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, colors, loading

Can someone tell me how to change the color of this loading bar for my Wordpress site? Is it a js that I need to change somewhere?

[image]

Massive thanks!

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use this CSS.

```
.pace .pace-progress {
   background: red !important;
}
```

You can find the div/CSS in use for this using the Chrome web inspector tool.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I used it bit I couldn't find the correct div that is the loading bar.

Comment: The code above is what you need. Add that CSS and the bar will go red.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as correct if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser inspector tool that can be found in the web developer tools (F12).

1. Enable the inspector tool, then click on the the element that you want to modifiy.
2. Note what is the id or the class of that element. For instance: `<span id="loading-bar"></span>`
3. Then modify its style using css. For instance: `#loading-bar { background-color: red; }`

You can do it in a .css file or directly in a html file under the `<styles></styles>` tag